# SQL doesn't show inserted data

Tags: sql, winforms

I have a table of users. So what I want to do is to fill it with a lot of data. So I created a query:

```
Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 1000
Begin 
   Insert Into users values ('Name-' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
          'Surname-' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name', 
          'Patronymic-' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)), 'user', 
          'emailemail-' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10))+'@gmail.com', 
          'Password' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)))
   Set @Id = @Id + 1 
End
```

Query was implemented. I expected to get 1000 objects. But for some bizarre reason it stopped there:

[image]

Firstly, I thought it didn't insert data. But then I registered a user using my application form and logged in and everything is fine (it checks if user exists in that table). So I wrote a code to see the ID of this user:

[image]

I updated the database a lot of times, though it still doesn't show anything after user with ID 1203.

Does anybody have any ideas about this?..

Comment: Your code works as expected in db<>fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b72a3d95ebcb6630b2e14a830448214).  I wonder if this is just an issue of how you are looking at the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you've helped me a lot! Thank you soooo much!